# Зачем нужен void в текущем случае?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Есть библиотека [**хуков**](https://usehooks-ts.com/)

Там есть хук  [**useFetch**](https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-fetch)

Вопрос заключается в том что я посмотрел на его код и не понял зачем там используется ключевое слово `void`

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  dispatch({ type: 'loading' })

  // If a cache exists for this url, return it
  if (cache.current[url]) {
    dispatch({ type: 'fetched', payload: cache.current[url] })
    return
  }

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, options)
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(response.statusText)
    }

    const data = (await response.json()) as T
    cache.current[url] = data
    if (cancelRequest.current) return

    dispatch({ type: 'fetched', payload: data })
  } catch (error) {
    if (cancelRequest.current) return

    dispatch({ type: 'error', payload: error as Error })
  }
}

void fetchData() // -> Как это работает?
```

Как это работает?
Это void TS-а или JS-a?

Изначально я думал что он там написан для того чтобы не писать `await`. Но потестировав этот код убедился что это не так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это обычный [оператор void](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void).

В данном случае используется что бы явно показать (коллегам, линтеру, самому себе через две недели) что мы не случайно забыли про результат функции, а сознательно его игнорируем.

На выполнение самой функции `fetchData()` он никак не влияет.